# Horizontal equal spacing of minipages

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, minipage

This:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \rule[0.5em]{13em}{0.5pt}\\
        %Text
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{flushleft} \large
        \rule[0.5em]{13em}{0.5pt}\\
        %Text
    \end{flushleft}
\end{minipage}\\[3cm]
```

produces:
[image]

Whereas, what I need is this:
[image]
... where the red zones are equally sized blank spaces and the grey zones are the margins.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: No need for `flushleft`. You can use `\raggedright`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need some `\hfill`s to stretch out the content equally:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\mbox{}% Left margin marker
\hfill% Horizontal stretch
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \rule[0.5em]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

  %Text
\end{minipage}%
\hfill% Horizontal stretch
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \rule[0.5em]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

  %Text
\end{minipage}%
\hfill% Horizontal stretch
\mbox{}% Right margin marker

\end{document}
```

<sub>Of course, an even spread with visible space on either side of the `minipage`s only works if the `minipage` widths don't take up the entire `\textwidth`. That is the case in your example, since `.5\textwidth` + `.5\textwidth` = `\textwidth`. I've reduced that to `.3\textwidth` each to show the effect of spreading.</sub>

Comment: Thanks, it looks much better now. However, only the middle `\hfill` seems to be having effect, as the minipages cling to the margins at each end, regardless of whether I keep `\noindent` or not. Any insights regarding this?

Comment: @Slaiyer: What are the widths of the `minipage`s?

Comment: 0.4\textwidth each

Comment: @Slaiyer: Could you provide code that shows this? I can't seem to replicate it. Either here (as an edit to your post) or as a paste on [Pastebin.com](http://pastebin.com).

Comment: @Slaiyer no, all the hfill will stretch equally, use `\dotfill` while debugging so you can see where the glue is being added.

Comment: Page code: http://pastebin.com/zWgBzcWP
Without line #13, the code (in a way) produces output identical to my problem image (the first one), i.e., only the middle and the right `\hfill` have any effect without the first `\mbox`.
Reading your comment for it, I had misinterpreted the purpose of `\mbox` (mistaken it for visual debugging), and didn't keep it at first as a consequence. It now works just fine and the last `\mbox` seems extraneous to my requirement in any case.
Thanks a lot, Werner and @David Carlisle.